# Ошибка кода Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, java, android

Я новичок. Полный новичок. 
При запуске **эмулятора** в **Android Studio** выходит следующая ошибка:

```
     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>     C:\Users\Алла\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Алла\AndroidStudioProjects\MySchool-balls\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Алла\AndroidStudioProjects\MySchool-balls\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
> Error Code:
>     1
> Output:
>     UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\РђР»Р»Р°\AndroidStudioProjects\MySchool-balls\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
>         at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>         at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

**Что делать?**

Comment: Многие программы не работают нормально, если в путях есть кириллица. Создайте пользователя для себя в латинице и запускайте там.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это известный баг Android Studio - перенесите студию в каталог с англоязычным наименованием и также желательно с именем без пробелов

> C:\Users\Алла\AppData\Local\Android

Причем тут Алла? :)

Comment: ну человек сидит не на своем компе

Comment: @Andreich украл?

Comment: ну почему сразу украл, есть множество более приличных вариантов

Comment: Кстати, этот баг можно побороть если в региональных настройках Windows задать правило перекодировки

Comment: Не нужно переносить AS, только SDK. Именно он не понимает кириллицу.